# How to remove write protection from sandisk cruzer switch pen drive?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, windows-xp, windows-8, usb-flash-drive

I have a sandisk cruzer switch pendrive. It is write protected. I want remove that write protection. I did Google very much i am not getting how to remove it.
I tried on mac also but it didn't worked for me.
So please can any one help me out to resolve this issue.?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

There is an easy way to Remove Write protection from pd.

Steps:

1. Open cmd as administrator
2. Type some commands

   1. `diskpart`
   2. `list disk`
   3. `select disk 1` (flash drive disk)
   4. `attributes disk clear readonly`  (or to set -- 'attributes disk set readonly')

Comment: for me, deleting the partitions in the disk one by one worked.

Comment: Thanks Souvik, It worked for me. My pendrive is sandisk cruser blade 4 GB.
I was able to list the files present in my pd, but neither i can copy into it nor from it to other place. Also i was not able to play video residing in pd.

Answer (score 0):

There may be 3 possibilities

1. your pen drive have a *physical lock* and if it is enabled make sure to disable it
2. try to format it with windows and if it does not allow you use "DISKPART" (it is run from command prompt for its commands google it  ) to format it
3. Use a LOW LEVEL FORMATTING TOOL to format it
4. If above methods are not working , Use DISKPART to check the status (the drive is read only OR not) and if it is showing "read only : no" your drive has a hardware problem contact service center

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since you asked but to help others,
I just did some deep hacks (ChkFlhs lol) and killed my sandisk which was write-locked, it was kind of a vegetable though,

In the [sandisk forums](http://forums.sandisk.com/t5/All-SanDisk-USB-Flash-Drives/Sandisk-cruzer-16GB-became-read-only/td-p/255218/page/2) someone sais that he contacted sandisk and they answered,

> I understand that you are getting write protection error while accessing your Cruzer flash drive. The flash drive has detected a potential fault and has become write protected to prevent data loss. There is no method to fix this. You will need to backup your data and replace the flash drive.
>   Our team of developers is in combination with the OS developers looking into a solution to resolve this issue.
>   Please note that only a minor percentage of users are experiencing the write protection issue and these are the customers posting on the internet to find a solution.

He also sais,

> SOLUTION 1: Return to where you bought and get a refund (as others usb drives might have the same issue)
>   SOLUTION 2: Contact Sandisk costumer service and get a refund, for the same reasons

Good luck sending your flashdisk to sandisk :)

Answer (score 0):

To disable write protection on a SanDisk 32GB flash drive (may work for a pen drive as well) –

After much research, I have stumbled across something that actually worked!

Click on 'Start' --> 'Run' --> type in 'regedit' and press enter.
Search for HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
Scroll down the list and click on SYSTEM
Click on CurrentControlSet
Click on Policies
Click on Microsoft
Click on FVE
In the panel on the right side, if the values for either FDVDenyWriteAccess OR RDVDenyWriteAccess are anything other than '0x00000000 (0)', right click and then click on 'Modify', then enter '0' and press Enter.
Remove the flash drive and reinsert. You can now copy to or write to the flash drive.

I am using Windows 7 Professional SP-1 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried all the aforementioned method, literally leaving no stone unturned. I think @ardokzal has a point. I have recovered undetectable pen-drives from their doomed state but never have I come across this issue. Also, why I support his point is because I scanned the sectors of the affected USB and actually found that the Drive had bad sector. Some right at the beginning.

If you were to ask me,

- SOL 1 : If USB is less than 5 years old apply for replacement.
- SOL 2 : If more than that, Try passing High voltage pulses (<12V) in different lines on the head, the drive is dead anyways, why not try some creativity with it. (DID NOT work for me).