# How to format write protected sandisk pendrive

Tags: usb-flash-drive

How to format `SanDisk Curzer Edge` 8GB pen drive when it is half bootable. Because of some laptop's charger issue i could not complete process. Now i want to format it but could not success. I have tried many solution which are available on net but not get success in any of them? 
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTg9A.png)

Comment: can you show us the error, if you have tried to format it.

Comment: you can check the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following:

1. Open "Computer Management"
2. "Storage" -> "Disk Management"
3. Make sure to find the correct device on the bottom panel
4. Right click on the partition rectange -> "Delete Volume"
5. Right click on the appeared grey area -> "Create Volume"

**edit:** If that doesn't work, you might need to use DISKPART utility to recreate filesystem and main partition, like in [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1446/how-can-i-reformat-my-sd-card-to-use-it-normally-again):

> Start a command prompt, and start the `DISKPART` console. List all of
>   your disks by typing `LIST DISK`, then select the proper disk with
>   `SELECT DISK #` (where # is the SD card). You can then type `CLEAN` to
>   clear the partition table on the card, effectively blanking it. MAKE
>   SURE YOU SELECTED THE PROPER DISK BEFORE RUNNING THE CLEAN COMMAND!
>
> To create a primary partition to reuse the space on the card, type
>   `CREATE PARTITION PRIMARY`. This will then reallocate the previously
>   "cleaned" space.
>
> To format, type `FORMAT FS=FAT32 QUICK`...

(Ignore the SD card being mentioned)

**edit 2:** If that doesn't work try suggestion from [this link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/change-external-hard-drive-from-read-only-back-to/1cc985e9-01b3-46ac-9108-8bc8e7968f36):

> 1) `list disk`
>   2) `select disk #`
>   3) `list volume`
>   4) `select volume #`
>   5) `detail disk`
>   6) `detail volume`
>   7) `attr disk clear readonly`
>   8) `attr volume clear readonly`
>   9) `detail disk`
>   10) `detail volume`

**edit 3**: [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/838836/606970) to a similar question suggests that the drive may be faulty:

> I understand that you are getting write protection error while
>   accessing your Cruzer flash drive. The flash drive has detected a
>   potential fault and has become write protected to prevent data loss.
>   There is no method to fix this. You will need to backup your data and
>   replace the flash drive. ...

Comment: The click is disabled. I can't click on it

Comment: Added an alternative option, edited the question. **Please be careful with it**

Comment: This also doesn't work. The Volume Status is Read only . Can you tell how to change it

Comment: I have used `regedit` to set value to 0 for off the write protect but still it show `the drive is write protected`

Comment: I have tired your Edit 2 , it doesn't work. `detail disk` show  `current read only`: _yes_ whereelse  `read only` : _no_

Comment: Added another alternative, edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running the Administrator account

1. Right click the file or folder that is write protected
2. Click Properties
3. Click Security Tab
4. Click Advanced
5. Click Owner Tab
6. Click Edit...
7. Select yourself as the owner then click apply

If it allowed you to take ownership you should now be able to delete the files

Comment: Not successfully.. Again showing error _write protected_

Answer (score 0):

Open CMD with administrator privileges then go to DISKPART and select the disk then type in ATTRIBUTES DISK, and Diskpart will tell you what you want to know about your flash drive. Most important is the first line Current Read-only State: Yes. This lets us know that, indeed, the flash drive is write protected.

To remove the write protection with Diskpart, type the command ATTRIBUTES DISK CLEAR READONLY. If it works, that will be confirmed by the line Disk attributes cleared successfully.